# Where can we find data through web crawling by nutch after the crawl completes?

Tags: hadoop, web-crawler, nutch

I have crawled website through apache nutch. I have done this process by order inject, segmentation, fetch, parse, updatedb. In which directory extracted data is present? As I was searched in all nutch directories like crawldb, segments, it was showing in unreadable format. After searching I have given dump command so that i am getting in html format. Is that right way of extracting data?
Thank you.

Comment: Please don't repost questions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086688/is-it-correct-when-we-crawl-websites-from-apache-nutch-the-data-will-come-in-htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use Solr to index those data. By that way you can filter the data by givin queries

```
http://lucene.apache.org/solr/
```